# How many intelligent species are in the Solar System in Heinlein's Future History?

Tags: future-history

In "Blowups Happen" characters discuss evidence that a civilization once existed on the Moon.

Intelligent Venusians or Venerians are seen in "Logic of Empire", different from those in *Space Cadet*, *Between Planets*, or *Podkayne of Mars*.

Martians are mentioned in several stories, but never described.  They might look like those in *Red Planet*, or in *Between Planets*, or different from both.

So what is the total number of contemporary intelligent species in our solar system in Heinlein's Future History series, and what planets and moons do they live on?

Answer (score 10):

"We Also Walk Dogs" mentions an interplanetary conference between all the inhabited planets and moons in the solar system.  And I have wondered what was the total number of intelligent species and which inhabited worlds, if any, are in the story but not named and thus open to speculation.

Clare considered the problems of making extraterrestrial visitors comfortable on Earth.

> ...Air pressure, humidity, radiation densities atmosphere, chemestry, temperatures, cultural conditions--those things are all simple.  But how about acceleration?  We could use a centrifuge for the Jovians, but Martians and Titans--that's another matter. There's no way to reduce Earth normal gravity...
>
> ...You know and I know that low-gravity people cannot spend more than a few hours in high gravity without seriously endangering their health...

So that makes four known species, Earth Humans, Jovians, Martians, and Titans.

Discussing possible methods of handling the gravity problem:

> "Wait a minute;"  Francis observed.  "Magnetism is a lot like gravity, isn't it?
>
> "well--yes."
>
> "Could there be some way to *magnetize* those gazebos from the little planets?  Maybe something odd about their biochemestry?"
>
> "Nice idea," Agreed Carson.  "but while their internal economy is odd, its not that odd. They are still organic."

Science marches on, and since "We Also Walk Dogs" was written animals as large as frogs have been levitated using magnets.

Anyway, if Francis was speaking literally there must be a civilization on at least one other small world in the solar system in addition to the one on Mars.  And if Francis was literally correct when he said "planets" there must be a civilization on a little world which is not a moon, but a planet like Mercury or a large asteroid like Ceres.  Or possibly Francis included moons like Titan when he spoke about "little planets".

The protagonists speculate about the purpose of the conference and whether they can make more money with smart investments:

> "Well," Said Grace.  "I think you can take it for granted that the real heavy-weights from all the planets are about to meet and divide Gaul into three parts."

"Yes, but who gets cut out?"

"Mars, I suppose".

"Seems likely.  With a bone tossed to the Venerians.  In that case we might speculate a little in Pan-Jovian Trading Corp."

So again there are Martians, Venerians, and Jovians in addition to Earthlings.

Later, the day before the conference starts, mention is made of the low gravity vehicles built for the Callistan delegation:

> "Perfectly.  I stepped into their sightseeing tank before we turned it over to them.  I was light as a proverbial feather.  Too light--I was very nearly spacesick."  He smiled in wry amusement. "I entered the Jovian apartments too.  That was quite another matter."

So "We Also Walk Dogs" has a solar system with at least six intelligent species - Venerians, Earth Humans, Martians, Jovians, Callistans from Callisto, a moon of Jupiter, and Titans from Titan, a moon of Saturn.

Are there any other worlds with intelligent natives in "We Also Walk Dogs"?  Hypothetically there could be intelligent beings living on any of the planets Mercury, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune, or Pluto, plus more species from the larger asteroids such as Ceres, or from the larger moons such as Io, Europa, & Ganymede of Jupiter, or Triton of Neptune.

When Beaumont describes the task:

> "Let us suppose you had to entertain a dozen representatives of each intelligent race in this planetary system and you wanted to make each one of them completely confortable and happy.  Could you do that?"

The dozen is the number of representatives of each planet and species, not the number of worlds with delegations.  So that does not help.

Later:

> Carson's departure left them with nothing to do until he reported back--nothing to do, that is, but to start action on the manifold details of reproducing the physical and cultural details of three other planets and four major satellites, exclusive of their characteristic surface-normal gravitational accelerations.

So that shows that there were four inhabited planets - Venus, Earth, Mars, and Jupiter, and four inhabited moons, Callisto, Titan, and two others.

And of those 7 other intelligent species, only Venerians are seen in person, in "Logic of Empire", and mentioned in a few other stories, and only the Martians are also mentioned several times.

The Jovians, Callistans, and Titans are mentioned only in "We Also Walk Dogs", and there are two other intelligent species on two unnamed large moons.

There is also the hypothetical extinct civilization on the Moon, speculated about in "Blowups Happen".

And that seems like a significant under use of those fictional intelligent species.

Added 01-13-21.  There are different opinions about which stories are part of the Heinlein future history.

Here is a link to a list of the stories included in *The Past Through Tomorrow*:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Past_Through_Tomorrow

> James Gifford[4] adds Time Enough for Love, which was published after The Past Through Tomorrow, and also "Let There Be Light", which was not included in The Past Through Tomorrow, possibly because the collection editor disliked it or because Heinlein himself considered it to be inferior. However, he considers Time Enough for Love to be a borderline case. He considers The Number of the Beast, The Cat Who Walks Through Walls, and To Sail Beyond the Sunset to be too weakly linked to the Future History to be included.
>
> Bill Patterson includes To Sail Beyond the Sunset, on the theory that the discrepancies between it and the rest of the Future History are explained by assigning it to the same "bundle of related timelines" in the World as Myth multiverse.[5] However, he lists a number of stories that he believes were never really intended to be part of Future History, even though they were included in The Past Through Tomorrow: "Life-Line" (which was written before Heinlein published the Future History chart; however, Lazarus Long does reference the protagonist of "Life-Line" and his device in Time Enough for Love), "The Menace from Earth", "—We Also Walk Dogs", and the stories originally published in the Saturday Evening Post ("Space Jockey", "It's Great to Be Back!", "The Green Hills of Earth", and "The Black Pits of Luna"). He agrees with Gifford that "Let There Be Light" should be included. The story "—And He Built a Crooked House—" was included only in the pre-war chart and never since.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_History_(Heinlein)#Definition

If Bill Patterson is correct that "We Also Walk Dogs" should not be considered part of the Heinlein future history, most of the solar system aliens in that story would be eliminated from the future history.  "We Also Walk Dogs" was published in *Astounding* using the pen name of Anson MacDonald, which strongly suggests that it wasn't considered part of the future history at that time.

So the hypothetical lunar civilzation in "Blowups Happen" and the small, amphibian natives of Venus in "Logic of Empire", and possibly the mention of Martians in "Ordeal in Space" (if that story is still considered part of the future history) a would be the only examples of intelligent aliens in the solar system I remember from the Future History.

Comment: That story always seemed shoehorned into the Future History. The technology never shows up again.

Comment: BTW, magnetic levitation wouldn't actually help. See [Does a magnetically suspended frog feel weightless?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73466/123208) & [What makes us feel heavy on Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/558643/123208). Of course, such real-world science is only relevant in a hard sci-fi story, but Heinlein generally *did* try to work on the harder side of the genre.

Comment: @PM 2Ring  I wouldn't want the aliens to feel weightless, I would want them to feel the normal weight they would feel on their home worlds, and to not suffer ill effects on their health from Earth's gravity.  I have no idea how well magnetic levitation would work for those aspects, and anyway the characters didn't have enough research time to perfect the process for Martians, Callistans, Titans, and two other species.  If the alien delegations got sick and died it would be a diplomatic disaster for Earth.

Comment: @Organic Marble  You are correct that "We Also Walk Dogs" doesn't fit very well with the rest of the Future History stories.  But it is listed in all the charts of it that were written or approved by Heinlein.  And on the third hand  I have noted that some critics do claim that "We Also Walk Dogs" and maybe other stories in the timeline are not really part of the series.

Answer (score 1):

I just read Heinlein's Future History Chart.
None of the books I reference below is included in it. However the OP references several books not on the chart so perhaps they meant to ask about all of Heinlein's works, not just those listed on the future history chart.

I felt sure that Mike from Stranger in A Strange Land was mentioned in the future history. Am I confused about this?

Some of the short stories included on the chart describe events that are honoured by the Cadets in Space Cadet.

There are well-described martians in Stranger in A Strange Land. The female nymphs,the male adults and the Old Ones who are ghosts and rule the society.

Willis in Red Planet seems similar to a martian nymph but the history does not match with Stranger in a Strange Land.

In Double Star completely different martians are described. Here is a very prejudiced description by a man who states that he does not like martians. His opinion changes over the course of the book.

> I didn't like Martians. I did not fancy having a thing that looks like a tree trunk topped off by a sun helmet claiming the privileges of a man. I did not like the way they grew pseudo limbs; it reminded me of snakes crawling out of their holes. I did not like the fact that they could look all directions at once without turning their heads—if they had had heads, which of course they don't. And I could not stand their smell!

In Space Cadet the all the Venerians they meet on Venus are female. There is speculation that there are males, weak and hidden from them.

> A triangular head, large as a collie’s, broke water about-ten feet from them. Tex jumped. The Venerian regarded ; him with shiny, curious eyes. Oscar stood up. “Greetings,  thou whose mother was my mothers friend.” The Venerian turned her attention to Oscar. “May thy mother rest happily.”She surface-dived and disappeared almost without a ripple.

and

> “Say, how about that, Oz? Are there really male Venerians, or is it just a superstition?”“Sure there are-the Little People are unquestionably bisexual. But I doubt if we’ll ever get a picture of one or a chance to examine one. The guys who claim to have seen one are mostly liars,”he added, “because their stories never add up.”“Why do you suppose they are so touchy about it?”“Why won’t a Hindu eat beef? There doesn’t have to be any reason for it. I go for the standard theory; the males are little and helpless and have to be protected.”

In Between Planets very different people from Venus are described.

> There was a queue waiting for cabs; he joined it. Beside the queue was sprawled the big, ungainly saurian form of a Venerian "dragon." When Don progressed in line until he was beside it, he politely whistled a greeting. The dragon swiveled one fluttering eyestalk in his direction. Strapped to the "chest" of the creature, between its forelegs and immediately below and in reach of its handling tendrils, was a small box, a voder. The tendrils writhed over the keys and the Venerian answered him, via mechanical voder speech, rather than by whistling in his own language. "Greetings to you also, young sir. It is pleasant indeed, among strangers, to hear the sounds one heard in the egg." Don noted with delight that the outlander had a distinctly Cockney accent in the use of his machine.

In Podkayne of Mars the martians are now extinct but two, again different,species with some degree of intelligence are described on Venus.

> here I am, some nowhere place out in the bush, in a room with no windows, and only one door. That door isn't much use to me as there is a fairy perched over it. She's a cute little thing and the green part of her fur looks exactly like a ballet tutu. She doesn't look quite like a miniature human with wings-but they do say that the longer you stay here the more human they look. Her eyes slant up, like a cat's, and she has a very pretty built-in smile.             I call her "Titania" because I can't pronounce her real name. She speaks a few words of Ortho, not much because those little skulls are only about twice the brain capacity of a cat's skull-actually, she's an idiot studying to be a moron and not studying very hard.

and the other Venus native

> It's got to be while Jojo is locked up."             "Jojo?"             "That set of muscles she has working for her. The native."            -             "Oh, you mean Pinhead."             "Pinhead, Jojo, Albert Einstein. The happy-duster. He serves supper, then he washes the dishes, then she locks him up and gives him his night's ration of dust. Then he stays locked up until he sleeps it off, because she's as scared of him when he's high as anybody else is. So we make our try for it while he is caged-and maybe she'll be asleep, too.

In Jerry was a Man an intelligent alien from our solar system is interviewed in court to establish that he is human legally. He has human rights.